# Speed up Class Constructors C++

Tags: c++, c++11

So I am doing speed tests for a system I wrote. For this I wrote my own DateTime namespace since I needed more control than ctime could give me and did not want to be bound to the system time. In my tests I have found that the constructors for the DateTimeParse and TimeZoneSpec classes are slowing down the construction of a DateTime object, even if it is roughly taking 3.4E-5 seconds this is done 200k which adds up.

There are two constructors that take about the same amount of time. The first creates a map of format specifiers, similar to the strtime formats (i.e. %z, %Y) storing their bounds and type as well as using std::function to bind a getter and setter (in applicable) to the proper function.

```
DateTimeParse::DateTimeParse()
{
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string,DateTimeFormat>::value_type("Y",DateTimeFormat('Y',4,"int",1970,3000,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_year, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_year, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("m",DateTimeFormat('m',2,"int",1,12,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_month, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_month, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("d",DateTimeFormat('d',2,"int",1,31,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_day, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_day, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("H",DateTimeFormat('H',2,"int",0,23,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_hour, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_hour, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("M",DateTimeFormat('M',2,"int",0,59,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_min, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_min, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("S",DateTimeFormat('S',2,"int",0,59,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_sec, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_sec, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("Z",DateTimeFormat('Z',3,"string",0,0,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_tz, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_tz, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("a",DateTimeFormat('a',3,"string",0,0, std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_weekday_abbr, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("A",DateTimeFormat('A',0,"string",0,0, std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_weekday_full, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("b",DateTimeFormat('b',3,"string",0,0, std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_month_abbr, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("B",DateTimeFormat('B',0,"string",0,0, std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_month_full, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("j",DateTimeFormat('j',3,"string",1,366,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_julian, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_julian, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("z",DateTimeFormat('z',3,"string",0,99,std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_tz_with_offset, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_tz_with_offset, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
  m_map.insert(std::unordered_map<std::string, DateTimeFormat>::value_type("s",DateTimeFormat('s',10,"ulint",static_cast<unsigned long int>(0),static_cast<unsigned long int>(4294967295),std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_set_epoch, this, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2), std::bind(&DateTimeParse::_get_epoch, this, std::placeholders::_1))));
};
```

The above is stored in std::map.

The second Constructor creates a std::vector> that contains time zone specifications.

```
TimeZoneSpec::TimeZoneSpec()
{
  std::vector<std::string> tz;
  std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > tzdb;

  tz = {"Greenwich, London","UTC","Coordinated Universal Time","","","-00:00:00","","","","",""};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"Greenwich, London","UTC","Coordinated Universal Time","","","+00:00:00","","","","",""};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"Greenwich, London","GMT","Greenwich Mean Time","","","00:00:00","","","","",""};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/New_York","EST","Eastern Standard Time","EDT","Eastern Daylight Time","-05:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/Chicago","CST","Central Standard Time","CDT","Central Daylight Time","-06:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/Denver","MST","Mountain Standard Time","MDT","Mountain Daylight Time","-07:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/Los_Angeles","PST","Pacific Standard Time","PDT","Pacific Daylight Time","-08:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/Anchorage","AKST","AKST","AKDT","AKDT","-09:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/Adak","HAST","HAST","HADT","HADT","-10:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();
  tz = {"America/Phoenix","MST","Mountain Standard Time","","","-07:00:00","+00:00:00","","","","+00:00:00"};
  tzdb.push_back(tz);
  tz.clear();

  m_tzdb = tzdb;
  };
```

I wondering if anyone has any ideas to speed this up. Again the time they take is small but when you do them 200K+ times it starts to add up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you modifying these structures? If not you could initialize them as static objects (edit: I guess not the map cuz those are bound to this)

Comment: *"the constructor for my DateTime namespace is slowing down the program"* - I have no idea, what that is supposed to mean.

Comment: Why are you using "m_map.insert(..., ("y", ...))" instead of the more readable `m_map["y"] = ...`? And for TimeZoneSpec ... all the copying, yeesh. Use `emplace_back` and construct directly into the `m_tzdb` vector.

Comment: it seems to me that DateTimeSpec could be a lightweight wrapper around a singleton since I don't think it carries any mutable state beyond the constructor. This way you'd pay the construction cost once only.

Comment: Why are you clearing the `tz`variable before reassigning it? It is a waste of time.